# Is there a way to provide user.js settings' management in Chrome?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, opera, userjs

I'm a developer of http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/86621, a simple script, which allows to monitor your websites' positions in Google SERPs.

A list of user's websites sets by an array in the beginning of the script. It was acceptable for me, until:

- some users asked about a simple way to add long lists of URLs
- I converted to Chrome, there isn't an "Edit script" button there

Is there any API, which help to access to settings by native browser way (via chrome://settings/extensionSettings, by clicking "Options" button)?

Also I'll be happy to know about such APIs for other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [Chrome Extension Options Page](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/options.html) to create an options button. [prefutils.js](http://mozilla.doslash.org/prefutils/) can be used by Firefox extensions to achieve the same effect.